# How are properties supplied on the command line accessed in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

```
java -Ddata=args -Dcommit=no -jar post.jar
```

In the above script,how are `data` and `commit` accessed in **java**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use [`System.getProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)):

```
System.getProperty("data");
System.getProperty("commit");
```

As the name suggests, these are system properties and not command-line arguments as your title suggests. Command-line arguments would be `java -jar post.jar arg1 arg2`

Comment: And command line arguments are accessed via the args parameter to `public static void main(String... args)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your main function, your passed a string array which contains arguments.

The Java tutorial has a program that shows you how this works:

```
public class Echo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (String s: args) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is only for arguments given to your code. Those particular ones you've shown are given to the Java interpreter itself and you can use [`System.getProperty()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) to access them:

```
String data = System.getProperty ("data");
String commit = System.getProperty ("commit");
```

Comment: -D actually sets system properties, they're not command-line arguments

Answer (score 0):

For the -D example

```
   String foo = java.lang.System.getProperty("data");
```

See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)